# How can I combine IFERROR formulas?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

Example

```
Car Tabs are $65 every 1 year ($5.42/month)
Oil Changes are $60 every 5 months ($12/month)
```

Formula for Years

```
=IFERROR((K5/L5)/12,"-")
```

Formula for Months

```
=IFERROR(K6/M6,"-")
```

Format

```
Description Monthly Yearly  Periodic    Years   Months
Car Tabs    $5.42   $65.00  $65.00      1
Oil Changes $12.00  $144.00 $60.00              5
```

I'd like a single formula to do either of these calculations.  I have two that do one or the other now.  How can I get my monthly calculation to take input from either months or years and error check?  Yearly is just calculated afterwords from monthly (multiplied by 12).  "Periodic" is where I enter the cost, then I enter a number for either "Years" or "Months", and the "Monthly"/"Yearly" get calculated.

Comment: Your IFERROR returns a text placeholder.  The description in the question suggests you don't want a placeholder.  Rather, you want to derive the missing value from the one with an input.  i.e., if Years has an input, Yearly is calculated and the Monthly value would be Yearly/12.  If Months has an input, Monthly would be calculated, and Yearly would be Monthly *12.  Can you clarify?

Comment: Why not just make your life easy and treat everything as months? 1 year = 12 months, on my planet, so then you just have a number every single time.

Comment: @fixer The intention is to clearly show when data is input incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
        A          B           C        D         E        F
1  Description  Monthly     Yearly  Periodic    Years   Months
2  Car Tabs     5.416666667   65       65         1 
3  Oil Changes  12            144      60                 5
4  not set      ?             ?        123
```

Columns D-F is source.

```
Cx=IF(Ex>0,Dx/Ex,IF(Fx>0,Dx/Fx*12,"?"))

Bx=IF(Cx="?",Cx,Cx/12)
```

Cell values which cannot be converted to number without error not allowed in source. You may add proper check/conversion (using `IF(ISNUMBER(Xx),Xx,"")`, for example) if needed.

Comment: Only the Yearly calculation works, but the monthly does not. It always returns an error. The Yearly returns correct calculations and error as intended.

Comment: @conman253 Shown table is a copy of real sample table which is worked correctly. Show/publish the source data which causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

Check if years has an entry if empty (true) then calculate from months if false calculate from years. If error return "-"

```
=IFERROR(IF(L5="",K5/M5,(K5/L5)/12),"-")
```

to include calculations with BOTH years AND Months divide months by 12 then add years before dividing

```
=IFERROR(IF(L5="",K5/M5,(K5/((M5/12)+L5))/12),"-")
```

Check your cell format for years and months are set to General and that Monthly Yearly and Periodic columns are set to Currency.

Comment: this returns error (-) for any entry: months, years, both, neither. i think it’s really close! please give it another look and thanks for the answer